# ImageView and ImageButtons crash app - Android

Tags: android

I have an xml file that has image views and image buttons, in my java, I am only refering to the layout, I am not even instantiating any objects, and the app is crashing with the following error:

```
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223): Process: me.docci.natter, PID: 2223
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{me.docci.natter/me.docci.natter.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at me.docci.natter.Login.onCreate(Login.java:12)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     ... 11 more
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     ... 25 more
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>    (ImageView.java:119)
05-14 08:07:40.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2223):     ... 28 more
```

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background_stripe"
android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSmallLogo"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_small"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
```

and the java:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: But it is just a layout file? how will that take up too much memory?

Comment: of course is not the layout the problem. Usually is due of bitmap. Do you how how to calculate the memory required to load a bitmap in memory?

Comment: issue with the images, but how do you calculate required memory load?

Comment: it takes width*height*4 bytes, for ARGB_8888

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Blackbelt I have figured out that it was the size(in kb) of files I was using. So I reduced them and it worked fine! Thanks!